# Difference between PHP web services and .NET web services

Tags: android, web-services

I want to learn how to consume web services in android , and i have done some research on it , i have seen that .net web services are in XML format and return response in XML, when PHP web services are give jason array in response , i have used ksoap for .net web services , is ksoap can also used for php web services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you misunderstood. .Net is not only to generate data in XML format.It is also possible to generate JSON data using .NET also and it is also possible to generate XML format using php.Most of the people will use JSON only because it is light weight and its easy parse from client side.Parsing XML data is really pain in my opinion.

And you asked ksoap also used for php?Yes it is.

See the below link
http://www.petetracey.com/2009/11/ksoap-with-php-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

Above site is my site so thought I'd clear this up a bit -- SOAP is a protocol that uses XML as its underlying format. It's one of many options that use XML. KSOAP (with the K) is the Java library, for blackberry but may be somewhere in the android libs or tacked on somehow. Still I think the better option is JSON, it is lighter weight and parses faster and therefore for mobile with data rates/limited processing power/battery consumption goes up with processor use -- you want to be lean and mean.

So any modern language, be it PHP, .NET, whathaveyou++, has libraries for both JSON and XML - and most have SOAP either built-in or as the 3rd party library somewhere. Which to use is the right tool for the job, and SOAP at this point is pretty much a legacy technology outside of the Sun/Oracle and Microsoft world.